# Pywinauto - select all data from a field

Tags: pywinauto

Is there any function that can be used to select all data(strings) from a field?

E.g. when you want to delete all the data from a field, and you manually select it and press delete.

I am currently doing this with DoubleClick() and Backspace key, but if the string contains spaces(e.g. "This is a string") it will only select the first word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you mean edit box text. The following code should help:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start('notepad.exe')
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.set_edit_text(u'some text')
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.set_edit_text(u'') # clean-up
```

It works silently (edit box can be out of focus).

For non-standard controls you may call `.type_keys('^a{BACKSPACE}')` if Ctrl+A is handled by the control.

Comment: Yes,I was referring to edit box text .It worked this way. Thank you Vasily!